# How to use commandline arguments in fish shell scripts

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to write an alias for `grep`:

```
# config.fish
alias grepcustom="grep -r $argv ~/"
```

Basically what I want this to do is a recursive grep on my home directory without having to type everything out (i know im lazy).

When I restart the shell and run `grepcustom` I get:

```
$ grepcustom "hello"
grep: hello: No such file or directory
```

There is a file that contains "hello". If I run `grep -r` in the shell it works properly. However, the problem seems to be with how my alias identifies the commandline argument "hello". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You're going to need to write an actual function:

```
$ alias grepcustom="grep -r $argv ~/"
$ type grepcustom
grepcustom is a function with definition
function grepcustom
    grep -r  ~/ $argv;
end
```

What happened there? Since I have not defined `$argv` in my shell, it's replaced by an empty string, and then `alias` added $argv to make the function work. Let's try with single quotes:

```
$ alias grepcustom='grep -r $argv ~/'
$ type grepcustom
grepcustom is a function with definition
function grepcustom
    grep -r $argv ~/ $argv;
end
```

That's clearly not right. You want

```
function grepcustom -a pattern
    grep -r $pattern ~/
end
```

Comment: This is interesting. What is `-a`?

Also in your second example, why was `$argv` placed both after `-r` and at the end of the statement?

Comment: the `-a` option to [the `function` command](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function) allows you to name your function arguments. `$argv` appears twice because `alias foo=bar` creates this: `function foo; bar $argv; end` -- i.e. [$argv is explicitly added](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#alias), no matter what `bar` is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know fish but two things.

1. The `$args` variable is likely already expanded in your alias.

   Run `alias grepcustom` or whatever fish command shows you the value of the alias and you should see that. You want single quotes on the alias definition for that.
2. Unless fish supports your manually placing `$argv` in the alias (instead of the normal location) this isn't going to work because aliases put arguments after the alias expansion. You would need a function for this.